# How to remove big pipe <script> tags from page response

Tags: theming, hooks

I need to remove `<script>` tags from some pages. I have managed to remove almost all of them, but these remain:

```
<script type="application/vnd.drupal-ajax" data-big-pipe-event="start"></script>

<script type="application/vnd.drupal-ajax" data-big-pipe-event="stop"></script>
</body>
```

How do I remove those scripts?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  How did you clean the HTML tags?  Is your goal to remove all of the `<script>` tags?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! If you strip off all the HTML tags, the page would just contain plain text, assuming that stripping off all the HTML tags doesn't include removing the content of those HTML tags. The question doesn't say which template you are changing, for which page/route that is, why you need to strip all the HTML tags. Removing all the HTML tags from a page requires at least to modify two template files.

Comment: That said, we would like to understand why you think you need to alter a template file to remove all the HTML tags. A module can output a plain-text page without altering any template file.

Comment: If you want to remove this script from a specific page then add the option `_no_big_pipe` to the route.

Comment: @4k4 Good spot, I edited and reopened feel free to put that in as an answer

Answer (score 2):

These scripts are added by the core module [BigPipe](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/big-pipe/overview).

If you want to remove them from a specific page then add the option `_no_big_pipe` to the route:

```
$route->setOption('_no_big_pipe', TRUE);
```

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones